# Spring application initalization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to initialize some beans during application start that will be reading from static shared in-memory structures. I was previously using @PostContruct but would like to shift to a more event-based initialization so that I can make use of Spring AOP features (Config, Resources, etc.) and avoid repeating myself.

All data beans implement this interface:

```
public interface DataInterface {
    public void loadData();

    public List<String> getResults(String input);
}
```

I have tried implementing both `ServletContextListener` and `WebApplicationInitializer` interfaces, but neither seem to get called.

```
@Service
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Autowired
    DataInterface[] dataInterfaces;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // This does not get called
        for (DataInterface interface : dataInterfaces)
            interface.loadData();
    }
}


@WebListener
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // does not get called
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // does not get called
    }
}
```

I could also try to initialize these classes at the end of the `main()` function that returns after I start the SpringApplication.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        // Can I initialize the DataInterfaces here???
    }
}
```

Seems like there should be a better way.

**Edit:**

I ended up using the following solution since I wasn't able to receive any of the `Context*` events listed in the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events-annotation).

```
@Component
public class DalInitializer implements ApplicationListener {
    @Autowired
    DataInterface[] dataInterfaces;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent applicationEvent) {
        if (applicationEvent.getClass() == ApplicationReadyEvent.class) {
            for (DataInterface interface : dataInterfaces)
                interface.loadData();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spring application event listeners, see [Better application events in Spring Framework](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)

Comment: This indeed works, but as expected or documented. I implemented a global ApplicationListener to see what events and settled on `ApplicationReadyEvent`. I did not see any of the `Context*` events listed in the [spring documentation] (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events).